# Init SQL scripts not executing in Kubernetes Deployment despite correct volume mounting and arguments

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I am deploying a Kubernetes Deployment using arguments to initialize paths to configuration files, but my init SQL scripts are not executing, and the databases with users are not being created. Here is my Deployment YAML:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: db
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: db
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        type: deployment
        app: db
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
              - matchExpressions:
                  - key: affinity-type
                    operator: In
                    values:
                      - postgres
      tolerations:
        - key: "key"
          value: "database"
          operator: "Equal"
          effect: "NoSchedule"
      volumes:
        - name: db-nfs-pvc
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: db-nfs-pvc
        - name: init-volume
          configMap:
            name: db-init
        - name: db-hba-conf
          configMap:
            name: hba-init
        - name: db-postgresql-conf
          configMap:
            name: postgresql-conf-init
      containers:
        - name: db
          image: postgres:14-bullseye
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: db
          volumeMounts:
            - name: db-nfs-pvc
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              subPath: staging/data
            - name: init-volume
              mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
            - name: db-postgresql-conf
              mountPath: /etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf
              subPath: postgresql.conf
            - name: db-hba-conf
              mountPath: /etc/postgresql/pg_hba.conf
              subPath: pg_hba.conf
          args:
            - "-c"
            - "config_file=/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf"
            - "-c"
            - "hba_file=/etc/postgresql/pg_hba.conf"
```

DB secrets:

```
      - POSTGRES_USER=admin
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/staging/data
```

I have verified that all files are properly mounted into their corresponding directories in the container. However, the init SQL scripts from /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d are not executing when the container starts, and the databases with users are not being created.
I made sure that if I comment out "args:", then the databases and user are initialized successfully, but then the necessary postgres configs are not initialized for me and vice versa, for if I leave it as in the code, I have the correct configs, but there are no databases and user.

How can I solve this issue and make sure the scripts run successfully during deployment? Any help would be appreciated!